# Chrome has started showing a separate, empty, DevTools window. Why?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

On OS X Sierra, Chrome (55.0.2883.95 64-bit) has started bringing up a separate, empty, DevTools window while I have a DevTools instance open, docked at the bottom of a Chrome tab. Why is this happening?

The screenshot below shows what the DevTools window looks like:

[image: DevTools window]

Comment: How does one re-produce this issue? It looks like it's a window that is trying to inspect the inspector, but failing to generate. I've not seen this currently, but if it's reproducible, log a bug (if not already existing): https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/list

Comment: @Gideon Not sure how it came about :( One possibility is that it was due to the extension The Great Suspender, which had suspended a tab with DevTools open. This thing started happening after this occurrence, although I can't say for sure there's causality.